# JSONPath expression to get a value from an array on condition or just the first value

Tags: json, jsonpath

Given JSON structured like this:

```
{
   "name":"Some Guy",
   "emails":[
      {
         "description":"primary",
         "status":"UNVERIFIED",
         "email":"first@first-email.com"
      },
      {
         "description":"home",
         "status":"VERIFIED",
         "email":"second@second-email.com"
      },
      {
         "description":"away",
         "status":"VERIFIED",
         "email":"third@third-email.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like a [JSONPath expression](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) to get the *first* email with status `VERIFIED` and if there are none, then just get the first email in the array. So, given the example above, the result would be `second@second-email.com`. Given this example:

```
{
   "name":"Some Guy",
   "emails":[
      {
         "description":"primary",
         "status":"UNVERIFIED",
         "email":"first@first-email.com"
      },
      {
         "description":"home",
         "status":"UNVERIFIED",
         "email":"second@second-email.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

the result would be `first@first-email.com`.

Is this possible with a JSONPath expression?

Comment: Which JSONPath implementation are you using? Do you need to do this in one expression?

Comment: Today I am using the jayway Java implementation, but if you have other implementations that would work I could figure out how to integrate that implementation.  I had in mind doing it in a single expression yes, but if you had a way where it could be expressed as a chain of expressions I'd be open to considering that.  It just can't require my own Java or Javascript code to process intermediate results.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You effectively have 2 JSONPath expressions, where the second one (first email) should be evaluated only if the first one (first verified email) returns nothing, so I don't think you can evaluate them both at the same time, in a single expression.

You can apply them one after the other, though:

```java
public static String getEmail(String json) {
    Configuration cf = Configuration.builder().options(Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS).build();
    DocumentContext ctx = JsonPath.using(cf).parse(json);
    List<String> emails = ctx.read("$.emails[?(@.status == 'VERIFIED')].email");
    if (!emails.isEmpty()) {
        return emails.get(0);
    }
    return ctx.read("$.emails[0].email");
}
```

If the email array is empty, `ctx.read("$.emails[0].email")` will return null instead of throwing an exception, thanks to the [option](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#options) `SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS`.

---

If you don't know the number of paths in advance:

```
public static String getEmail(String json, String[] paths) {
    Configuration cf = Configuration.builder().options(Option.ALWAYS_RETURN_LIST, Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS).build();
    DocumentContext ctx = JsonPath.using(cf).parse(json);
    for (String path : paths) {
        List<String> emails = ctx.read(path);
        if (!emails.isEmpty()) {
            return emails.get(0);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The [option](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#options) `ALWAYS_RETURN_LIST` means the return type is a list, even when you have one or zero results.

Comment: The issue is that I just have some JSON input and a map keys to JSONPath expressions.  I don't know what the expressions are up front - they are configurable, so having something like this `getEmail` method is not going to work for me.

Comment: @jhericks The method is more for demonstration. You can apply those 2 expressions one after the other, so you can turn both of the hard-coded expressions in my example into arguments.

Comment: Say I had an array of expressions: `["$.emails[?(@.status == 'VERIFIED')].email", "$.emails[0].email"]`  What would a method look like that would just iterate through these expressions and give the correct email?

Comment: @jhericks you use `ALWAYS_RETURN_LIST` to make sure all reads return a list type, then loop through the paths. Answer updated.

Comment: That still doesn't quite do it for me, because we have to support things like the simple JSONPath: `$.emails` in which case, they would _want_ the list returned, but this gives me enough to go on.  This is not the answer I was hoping for, but if no one comes up with anything superior in the next few days, I will accept your answer and award the bounty.

Comment: Actually, I do have a follow-up.  Is there a way to modify the `$.emails[?(@.status == 'VERIFIED')].email` expression itself to just return the first match (rather than a list)?  I know `$.emails[?(@.status == 'VERIFIED')].email[0]` doesn't work but that's the kind of thing I'm looking for.

Comment: @jhericks No, unfortunately. You can't combine a "where" clause and an index access. You can modify `getEmail` to always return a list and decide later on if you want to pick only the first one.

Comment: @jhericks For combining a filter with an index access, there's an open issue: https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath/issues/272

Answer (score -1):

This code should work perfectly for you

```
//Use the json parsing library to extract the data
    JsonPath jp = new JsonPath(json); 
    Map<String, Object> location = jp.get("name.emails[0]");
    System.out.println(location);
```

Comment: This doesn't take the email.status into account.

Comment: It shoul do. All the parameters of the first record will be captured. Print 'location' to console to verify

Comment: Another problem here is that you cannot assume the ordering of entries.  A JSon array resembles to a JSon unordered list.

Comment: I don't mean that 'status' wouldn't be included.  I mean it would just always get the first email without regard for whether status == 'VERIFIED' or not. 
 Would it give a different result for the two JSON examples given?